# Call a function continuously after key is pressed in C

Tags: c, function, loops, call

I want to be able to call my function that moves my propellers (OpenGL work) after I press the 'a' key. Here's what I have set up:

```
switch (key)
{
    case 'a':
        startShip = 1;
        while (1 (&& startShip == 1)) {
            spinPropeller();
        }
}
```

I get caught in an infinite loop. I've tried using a timer function but I'm not sure how to implement it properly. I want my propellers to spin and not stop until the program is closed.

edit: program should close after detecting a 'q' key

Comment: I think there should be a `:` right after `case 'a'`.

Comment: It is quite impossible to tell what is wrong as long as we do not see, what (and how ) changes the value of `startShip `.

Comment: I'm trying to show that after key 'a' is pressed, startship changes value to 1, showing the program it is ready to move, and the propeller will keep spinning

Comment: Also, I do not know if this line: `while(1 (&& startShip == 1 ))` compiles for you, possibly not as it will interpreted as a function so I would change it to:
`while(1 && (startShip == 1 ))`.

Comment: I see that `startShip = 1;`  but then it will stay 1 for ever, you won't be able input a new key because your code will only execute the `spinPropeller`. If you want to stop it you have to wait for a new key inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Yup, that works. I get caught in an infinite loop, not sure what I can do to get out. As soon as key 'a' is pressed, spin the propellers until program is closed.

Comment: You should add into your question, when do you want to leave the loop exactly, on what conditions.

Comment: Ah, program should close upon 'q' key

Comment: You should have a frame updating loop, and put the keyborad detecting call in that. In glfw, you could use `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) { //.. put your always run code in here }`.  if you really want to call it out of loop forcely, you could make a thread and do it forever...

Comment: You have an infinite while loop with no exit condition. You should implement your program as described in Selbies answer, an infinte loop with the polling and action code within. You haven't added a case for the Q key hence it will not do anything.

Comment: `while (1 (&& startShip == 1))` is a syntax error. Please post your real code.

Answer (score 2):

Game loops work like this:

```
while (true)
{
    get_input();   // get keyboard, mouse, and joystick input

    move_items();  // update the player position and all other items in the game, fire weapons, and update game state

    collision_detection();  // figure out what hit what and update game state

    render();   // draw your OpenGL scene
}
```

To make this happen, your get_input function or equivalent needs to read keyboard state in a non-blocking manner.  I think OpenGL or GLUT has a helper function for this, but the implementation will likely be platform specific.